# ¿Como agregar https a una instancia de subred privada dentro de una VPN AWS?

Tags: https, aws, vpn

He creado una conexión VPN entre mi entorno de AWS y un cliente, el cliente como requerimiento a solicitado acceso a una instancia dentro de subred que se comunique dentro de la VPN por https.

Existe un load balancer frente a las instancias ya que las instancias las creé con Elastic Beanstalk y le he entregado las ips de las interfaces de red al cliente y cuando prueba por http, funciona bien.

El problema viene cuando el cliente intenta por medio de https por medio de la VPN, donde habilito los puertos del load balancer para permitir la entrada por puerto 443 y agrego un certificado SSL, pero el cliente no lo puede acceder desde la VPN; por otro lado yo desde SoapUi o Postman lo puedo consultar sin problemas, hasta puedo ver el certificado que se está utilizando.

¿Cómo puedo implementar https de esa instancia pero para el cliente que utiliza la conexión de VPN?. El acceso a internet a la instancia no es importante, pero sí el acceso del cliente al servicio por medio de la VPN utilizando https.

La configuración de VPN es clásica para AWS y la subred es expuesta por propagación de rutas al VPN.

Comment: la vpn esta configurada la vpn por PPTP,  site to site, L2TP, IPSec, MPLS, y VPN híbrida. y cuando te refieres al acceso a la instancia `https` por `443` es un acceso tipo cierto?

Comment: Side to Side, si puedo acceder a las instancias por http, pero necesito habilitar el https para una de ellas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No es factible agregar un certificado a una ip, ya que para agregar un certificado estos se ligan a nombres de dominio los cuales pueden ser constantes en el tiempo a diferencia de las ips. Desde el punto de vista del cliente los accesos a las instancias vía Site to Site se realizan por ip solamente, la conexión interna a través del túnel no da espacio para resolver un dns para que alcance las instancias internas.